# What is the best way to keep track of the id of an element selected from an auto-suggest textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an auto-suggest textbox. A user can either pick an already existing item in the database of type in a new one.

How do i keep track of the id if item was selected (Store the id of the list of items coming from the db)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the items from the DB, load it as a JSON string, so both the values and their associated IDs are passed into your javascript. You can even index it by the value:

```
var index = {};
index["some value"] = "some_id";
```

Then, when you are going to submit to the DB again, just reference for the ID.

Comment: I will store the ids in id attribute of the li element.

Answer (score 1):

The best choice depends upon the context.  There are many ways to do this.

As Jordan suggested, use the `<input type="hidden" ...>` in a form, especially if the value will be submitted via a form.

Store the value in in a javascript `var` or `object`.

There is jQuery's [**Data Cache**](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals).  This is a simple key value store.

```
$("body").data("key","foo");
$("body").data("key"); // returns "foo"
```

And you could store the value in a `cookie.` Which might make sense if you want the value to persist.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the ID of the existing item to a hidden `<input>` element. When posting the form, you could first check for a value in the hidden `<input>` element. If there isn't one, use the value from the other text `<input>`.